# Add a gradient feather to an image

Tags: vector, gradient, effects

So I have an image of a map and I want the top & bottom edges of the map to blend out into a gradient blue background.

I'm a compositor so am only really familiar with InDesign. I've managed to feather the bottom of the image but can't work out how to do the same to the top. How can I feather the top to match the bottom?

[image]

Comment: "I have managed to feather the bottom of the image" How did you do that and why can't you do the same to the top?

Comment: If the below answer did answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess: did you use Gradient feather effect? In which case you can only feather one side.

Use Directional feather instead: it will allow you to apply feather on both top and bottom sides:

[image: directional feather]